# is there a way to load faster on internet explorer a javascript and a selecting table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a script with a table, work on internet explorer faster!! on chrome works fine.
Any suggestions??

A live demo you can see here http://megatrixads.com/cbm

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IE9 have built-in JavaScript profiler. Have you tried to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested generating the map from a js object and it works like a charm in IE.

Here is the code I used to generate the map object from your html (I've edited first tr before running it, so it will generate correct result, tr with td in same format as all the others, with colspan)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var trIndex = 0,
       mapObj = {},
       tdIndex = 0;; 

   $table = $('.selectable');

   $('tr', $table).each(function() {
       mapObj[trIndex] = [];
       tdIndex = 0;
       $('td', $(this)).each(function() {
           if($(this).attr('colspan') > 0) {
               mapObj[trIndex][tdIndex] = {colspan: $(this).attr('colspan')}
           } else {
               mapObj[trIndex][tdIndex] = {id: $(this).attr('id')}
           }
           tdIndex++;
       });
       trIndex++;
   })
   console.log(JSON.stringify(mapObj));
});
```

Then I used this object to generate the table, all you need to have for the table is:

```
<table width="1160px" height="695px" class="selectable"></table>
```

The JavaScript to generate your map, I've put in a fiddle because the generated object is too big to post here. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/u8AwJ/

Of course code can be optimized more, but time is limited for me at the moment.

This is only related to generating the map (I have removed the actions you had so I can make it work - the rendering I mean). You can add that part back.

Comment: thanks i will try it and let you know i thing it will be ok!!

Answer (score 2):

As said in the answers above. Try using a profiler. I've been reading up on the performance-improvements for JS. This is a [great book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802806.do)

I've checked out your code and there are some things you can do.

To render the page quicker. Start by adding all JS not in the HEAD but after all te markup. So after the CENTER Tag! This way HTML/css will be loaded/rendered before the JS starts executing. The loading of JS will stop all rendering because JS is able to change things in the DOM.

Try to use a document.ready()

Try putting all the JS in 1 file and minimize or pack it => it will improve the load/nr of requests to the server.

I see that in your selectable() statement you quite often call upon $('.ui-selected') and $('.ui-selected').length() => Store this el in a variable. So just do var $ui_selected = $('.ui-selected'); This way Jquery won't search the DOM everytime to select this element!(By the way, using a class to find a element, is less performant then using a #ID

I Hope these tips are useful to you!

Comment: can you show me on this fiddle how to do  $ui-selected var  http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/63/

Comment: This is the fiddle you asked for: http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/64/
I've also edited the confirmation($ui_selected.length + " box selected. It will cost "+($ui_selected.length*150 + " Euros")) rule. Your passing a parameter to function that doesn't accept one. So i altered it

Comment: Well, it loads for me in IE9, what version of IE do you have? (for 8 it doesn't). You could try having an array or object in JavaScript and create the dom with jQuery. This way it will probably load in IE7/IE8, and you could also keep track loading/saving with ajax of users selections easier.

Comment: Is it giving any errors in IE < 9? Or doesn't it rendern in ie8 and below? Just try using the html and remove all js from it. If IE8 & below isn't able to render it then the table is probably to big or mayby the html isn't valid(don't know, didn't test it)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using built in Profiler in IE9:

F12 (or Tools-> Developer tools) -> Profiler -> Start profiling.

If you need IE7/IE8 to render faster you still may try to profile in IE9 and see if there are obvious performance issues (like too many calls to particular function). Note that most libraries have special code path for older browsers like IE6-8, so forcing browser/document mode to be IE7/8 while useing dev tools in IE9 may be necessary to find particular issues.

Comment: is it better that  the script i am using should be changed or it will not make any difference?

Comment: I don't know. I have not looked at your link - if you have specific concerns - please paste samples into your question.

Comment: basicaly it will not open with internet explorer. With chrome works fine